# IOS CPP static library creation

Tags: c++, ios, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile cpp code to iOS.
I was able to compile the code by following  [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)

After creating the static library I'm taking the .a file and all the include files and adding it to some iOS project and project copmile just fine.

Once I'm trying to use the static lib by adding an include statement to one of the headers I'm getting compile errors.

In the cpp source all the files are with folder hierarchy and after the static lib creation they are located all in the same folder.

If I have in my SDK.h file `#include <MYCOMPANY/common/cool.h>` it will cause an error.

It seems every time I create the static lib I need to change includes in the .h files.

Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing? Any way to refactor it so that all the things will work even after the static library creation?

Comment: what error exactly do you see?

Comment: header file not found